# appcfg appengine 502 Proxy error in localhost

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to upload some data to my local datastore in appengine.
The command I am using is the next one:

```
    appcfg.py upload_data --config_file="C:\config.yml" --filename="C:\mycsv.csv" --url=http://localhost:8888/remote_api --kind=MyEntity
```

The problem is that I'm working behind my company proxy and I am getting the next ERROR even trying to connect to the localhost server:

```
    Error Code: 502 Proxy Error. The ISA Server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). (12202)
```

It seems the authentication is ok, but somehow the proxy tries to filter my connection to my own computer.

Some ideas about how can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove/disable proxy settings of your network then try the above command.
I was facing the similar issue and this issue resolved when i disable my proxy settings.

Comment: I solved the problem deleting the proxy setting from my windows variables (http_proxy and https_proxy), once I restarted the computer it worked. I guess it was trying to redirect all the traffic throw the proxy when it shouldn't because it's in local.